# XSLT Remove Parent Element without affecting children

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my inputxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag:dataList xmlns:tag="http://www.example.com/tempuri">
<Item>Data1</Item>
<Item>Data2</Item>
</tag:dataList>
```

And Below is my xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tag="http://www.example.com/tempuri">
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <xsl:element name="tag:dataRef">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The response that i am getting from the xslt is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag:dataList xmlns:tag="http://www.example.com/tempuri">
<tag:dataRef>Data1</tag:dataRef>
<tag:dataRef>Data2</tag:dataRef>
</tag:dataList>
```

But the response that i am trying to get is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag:dataList xmlns:tag="http://www.example.com/tempuri">
    <tag:dataRef>Data1</tag:dataRef>
</tag:dataList>
<tag:dataList xmlns:tag="http://www.example.com/tempuri">
    <tag:dataRef>Data2</tag:dataRef>
</tag:dataList>
```

How can i achieve this using xslt?

Looking forward to your solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The response you are trying to get is invalid XML. There can't be multiple elements at the root level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating parent element in match template. For desired output you need to do like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tag="http://www.example.com/tempuri" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag:dataList">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <tag:dataList xmlns:tag="http://www.example.com/tempuri">
            <xsl:element name="tag:dataRef">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </tag:dataList>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**NOTE:** Here you have multiple parent element so you need to wrap all element inside one  root element as per XML standard.